# Looking for a ffmpeg command line to create a slide show from jpg files in a folder

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have folders in Windows, containing jpg files (about 50 in one folder) created periodically by a webcam. These files are named P21013010143010.jpg, P21013010343310.jpg, ... From these files I would like to create a kind of slide show or video (mp4, avi, ...). I found some examples using ffmpeg, so I installed it and tried a little - but unfortunately without success. All examples I found are something like

ffmpeg -f image2 -i .jpg -s foo.avi

Unfortunately I could not find a pattern, that matches my file names "P", followed by 14 digits and ".jpg". Is there a chance to use simply something like "P*.jpg" or a regex?

If there is a way to get this, how will ffmpeg sort the files? I would need the files sorted ascending.

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: Are you on Windows or on Linux, cause using a mask like "P*.jpg" doesn't currently work on Windows versions of ffmpeg...

Comment: I'm working under Windows. Glob seems to not work under Windows, too.

Comment: You didn't specify nothing for the -s switch, it expect a screen resolution like -s 1280x720....

Comment: OK. So if I remove "-s", it will use the resolution of the jpg files (of course all of the same resolution) or do I have to specify this always?
But beside this: P*.jpg or glob still won't work under windows.

Comment: You have to create a filelist in your case, would a batch file be a solution?

Comment: Yes - I just saw, that you wrote a batch file and posted it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The batch file creates the filelist automatically let me know if it works as expected..

Comment: It works. Please see my comment under your bat script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this batch file to do the job. Copy the following code to notepad, save it with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension. Drag and drop the folder where the images are to the batch file. It will ask what time interval you want in seconds between the images, when ready It should create a mp4 video from the images you draged to it...

```
@echo off

if /i exist "%~1" (if /i not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

echo.
Set /p "Interval=What time interval in seconds would you like to have? "

set HResolution=1280
set VResolution=720

pushd "%~1"
if /i exist "%~n1.tmp" del /q "%~n1.tmp"
if /i exist "%~dp0%~n1.mp4" del /q "%~dp0%~n1.mp4"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on *.jpg *.png') do (
                                                       echo file '%%a'>>"%~1\%~n1.tmp"
                                                       echo duration %Interval% >>"%~1\%~n1.tmp"
                                                      )

ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i "%~n1.tmp" -vf "scale='min(%HResolution%,iw)':'min(%VResolution%,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=%HResolution%:%VResolution%:-1:-1" "%~1.mp4"
if /i exist "%~n1.tmp" del /q "%~n1.tmp"
```

IF you want higher or lower vídeo resolution change the part at set HResolution= & set VResolution=

the filelist is actually:

file 'file 01.jpg'

duration 3

file 'file 02.jpg'

duration 3

file 'file 03.jpg'

duration 3

.....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it and it worked fine

So if I would like to start ffmpg from another script, I have let this script create the tmp file containing the jpg file names and durations and then execute your command line using the file created by my script (and of course the choosen resolution)?
If I understood correctly, the tmp file must be like this

file P22020806532010.jpg
duration 1
file P22020807132010.jpg
duration 1

And last question: is there a chance to use a duration < 1 second, e.g. 250 ms?

Comment: OK, tmp file format is clear now.

Comment: Please look at the editis for how the filelist should look like but yes you create the filelist and can use the ffmpeg command as you like with your changes. For times lower than 1 second you can specify 0.500 (half a second) 0.250 (one forth of a second) and so on.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help. I have a groovy script that downloads webcam pictures from a ftp server periodically. This script can create the file list file and then call the command line. I'll try this later this evening or tomorrow. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: It is done: my groovy scripts builds the file list and uses your command line to create the mp4. It works perfectly.
Thank you very much!